# Record not getting deleted from MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I added a record in a table in MySQL database, now I am trying to delete that particular record from table, but it is not getting deleted & showing this message:

> #1062 - Duplicate entry '3107' for key 'PRIMARY'

How do I delete this entry?

Comment: which query you have try to DELETE it ?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

Comment: Remember that you must COMMIT your changes.

Comment: @BerndBuffen I tried to delete the record by both running sql query and selecting the delete option for that record but it is not getting deleted. Showing me the same message as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get this error during `DELETE`. UPDATE or INSERT can return that
So either you are not running `DELETE` or you have trigger on your table, that is making some other changes, that give you that error.

If child tables have `ON DELETE CASCADE`,check them for triggers as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table_name [where condition];
```

use this statement, replace `table_name` with your table name and put the condition.

If you do not specify `where` clause, every records will be deleted.

Comment: Tried this as well but still the same message is showing

Comment: May I know your statement which you have used. ?